# Calling a Python script function from C# Form

Tags: python, c#, winforms, ironpython

I'm trying to call a specific Python file's function from a C# Form, but I think that I keep having problems with IronPython due to the usage of custom libraries (Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token' shows up when creating scope). Can the IronPython problem be solved or are there any alternative ways to do it?

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

**PythonScript:**

```
import customLib

def functionA:
        print("Hello, world!")

def functionB:
        customFunc()
        print("Goodbye!")
```

**customLib:**

```
def customFunc:
       //do something
```

**C# Form**

```
//calls PythonScript.FunctionB only
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `Process` class which provides access to local and remote processes and enables you to start and stop local system processes.

Try something like this:

```
 private void run_script()
 {

        string fileName = @"C:\your_script.py";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Python27\python.exe", fileName)
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine(output);

        Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering! May I ask you how can I use the `Process` Class to call only one function in the script instead of executing it entirely?

Comment: Well, for this i will recommend using `IronPython` (:

Comment: I tried to use it but I think that there are some problems when importing a non-native library in the executed script. Is it true or am I missing something?